# Add property to object(s) that start or end a streak of values

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

I have an array of objects that looks like this:

```
let segment = [
  {timestamp: "2020-09-23T14:01:59.425Z", jam_factor: 5.12002},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-24T20:02:20.656Z", jam_factor: 3.13285},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-24T21:02:28.307Z", jam_factor: 2.84637},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-24T22:04:09.648Z", jam_factor: 3.57281},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-24T23:02:10.257Z", jam_factor: 10},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-25T04:00:54.857Z", jam_factor: 10},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-25T05:01:47.202Z", jam_factor: 10},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-25T06:02:27.773Z", jam_factor: 10},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-25T07:01:43.621Z", jam_factor: 10},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-25T08:01:07.918Z", jam_factor: 10},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-25T09:02:48.843Z", jam_factor: 5.2812},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-25T10:02:44.509Z", jam_factor: 10},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-25T11:01:47.002Z", jam_factor: 10},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-25T12:02:46.718Z", jam_factor: 10},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-25T13:00:32.164Z", jam_factor: 10},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-28T05:02:44.037Z", jam_factor: 10},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-28T14:01:57.837Z", jam_factor: 10},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-29T11:01:34.661Z", jam_factor: 10},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-29T17:02:20.367Z", jam_factor: 10},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-29T18:02:23.282Z", jam_factor: 8.39212},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-29T19:00:39.818Z", jam_factor: 7.38261},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-30T03:01:49.720Z", jam_factor: 6.28182},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-30T05:01:35.621Z", jam_factor: 5.98176},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-30T06:00:27.023Z", jam_factor: 5.98176},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-30T07:03:00.132Z", jam_factor: 4.15984}
];
```

The function below loops through this array and filters/returns entries that end a (minimum) streak of three lower values (<10), **and** at the same time start a (minimum) streak of three higher values (10). This also works the other way around (filter entries that end a streak of three higher values (10) **and** at the same time start a streak of three lower values.)

```
function filter(segment) {
  let result = [];
  let count = 0;
  let prevIsTen, j;
  for (let i = 0; i < segment.length; i++) {
    let isTen = segment[i].jam_factor === 10;
    if (isTen === prevIsTen) {
      if (++count == 3 && j) result.push(segment[j]);
    } else {
      j = count < 3 ? 0 : i;
      count = 1;
    }
    prevIsTen = isTen;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Now I would like to add an extra property indicating whether a streak of three **higher** values (10) has started ("start") or ended ("end"). Like so:

```
{timestamp: "2020-09-24T23:02:10.257Z", jam_factor: 10, start_end: "start"},
{timestamp: "2020-09-29T18:02:23.282Z", jam_factor: 8.39212, start_end: "end"}
```

I am aware I could use `segment[j].start_end = "start"` but find it difficult to pinpoint how and where to add these "start" and "end" values

Comment: what should happen, if the array has no starting items with factor smaller than ten? `j` is supposed to act as flag and index, but not for the first item ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add that property to the result returned by `filter`, just change

```
result.push(segment[j]);
```

to:

```
result.push({ ...segment[j], start_end: isTen ? 'start' : 'end' });
```

```js
let segment = [
  {timestamp: "2020-09-23T14:01:59.425Z", jam_factor: 5.12002},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-24T20:02:20.656Z", jam_factor: 3.13285},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-24T21:02:28.307Z", jam_factor: 2.84637},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-24T22:04:09.648Z", jam_factor: 3.57281},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-24T23:02:10.257Z", jam_factor: 10},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-25T04:00:54.857Z", jam_factor: 10},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-25T05:01:47.202Z", jam_factor: 10},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-25T06:02:27.773Z", jam_factor: 10},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-25T07:01:43.621Z", jam_factor: 10},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-25T08:01:07.918Z", jam_factor: 10},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-25T09:02:48.843Z", jam_factor: 5.2812},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-25T10:02:44.509Z", jam_factor: 10},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-25T11:01:47.002Z", jam_factor: 10},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-25T12:02:46.718Z", jam_factor: 10},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-25T13:00:32.164Z", jam_factor: 10},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-28T05:02:44.037Z", jam_factor: 10},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-28T14:01:57.837Z", jam_factor: 10},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-29T11:01:34.661Z", jam_factor: 10},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-29T17:02:20.367Z", jam_factor: 10},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-29T18:02:23.282Z", jam_factor: 8.39212},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-29T19:00:39.818Z", jam_factor: 7.38261},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-30T03:01:49.720Z", jam_factor: 6.28182},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-30T05:01:35.621Z", jam_factor: 5.98176},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-30T06:00:27.023Z", jam_factor: 5.98176},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-30T07:03:00.132Z", jam_factor: 4.15984}
];

function filter(segment) {
  let result = [];
  let count = 0;
  let prevIsTen, j;
  for (let i = 0; i < segment.length; i++) {
    let isTen = segment[i].jam_factor === 10;
    if (isTen === prevIsTen) {
      if (++count == 3 && j) result.push({ ...segment[j], start_end: isTen ? 'start' : 'end' });
    } else {
      j = count < 3 ? 0 : i;
      count = 1;
    }
    prevIsTen = isTen;
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(filter(segment));
```

If you want to modify the original array, you can do that when you push to `result`:

```
if (++count == 3 && j) {
    result.push(segment[j]);
    segment[j].start_end = isTen ? 'start' : 'end'
}
```

```js
let segment = [{
    timestamp: "2020-09-23T14:01:59.425Z",
    jam_factor: 5.12002
  },
  {
    timestamp: "2020-09-24T20:02:20.656Z",
    jam_factor: 3.13285
  },
  {
    timestamp: "2020-09-24T21:02:28.307Z",
    jam_factor: 2.84637
  },
  {
    timestamp: "2020-09-24T22:04:09.648Z",
    jam_factor: 3.57281
  },
  {
    timestamp: "2020-09-24T23:02:10.257Z",
    jam_factor: 10
  },
  {
    timestamp: "2020-09-25T04:00:54.857Z",
    jam_factor: 10
  },
  {
    timestamp: "2020-09-25T05:01:47.202Z",
    jam_factor: 10
  },
  {
    timestamp: "2020-09-25T06:02:27.773Z",
    jam_factor: 10
  },
  {
    timestamp: "2020-09-25T07:01:43.621Z",
    jam_factor: 10
  },
  {
    timestamp: "2020-09-25T08:01:07.918Z",
    jam_factor: 10
  },
  {
    timestamp: "2020-09-25T09:02:48.843Z",
    jam_factor: 5.2812
  },
  {
    timestamp: "2020-09-25T10:02:44.509Z",
    jam_factor: 10
  },
  {
    timestamp: "2020-09-25T11:01:47.002Z",
    jam_factor: 10
  },
  {
    timestamp: "2020-09-25T12:02:46.718Z",
    jam_factor: 10
  },
  {
    timestamp: "2020-09-25T13:00:32.164Z",
    jam_factor: 10
  },
  {
    timestamp: "2020-09-28T05:02:44.037Z",
    jam_factor: 10
  },
  {
    timestamp: "2020-09-28T14:01:57.837Z",
    jam_factor: 10
  },
  {
    timestamp: "2020-09-29T11:01:34.661Z",
    jam_factor: 10
  },
  {
    timestamp: "2020-09-29T17:02:20.367Z",
    jam_factor: 10
  },
  {
    timestamp: "2020-09-29T18:02:23.282Z",
    jam_factor: 8.39212
  },
  {
    timestamp: "2020-09-29T19:00:39.818Z",
    jam_factor: 7.38261
  },
  {
    timestamp: "2020-09-30T03:01:49.720Z",
    jam_factor: 6.28182
  },
  {
    timestamp: "2020-09-30T05:01:35.621Z",
    jam_factor: 5.98176
  },
  {
    timestamp: "2020-09-30T06:00:27.023Z",
    jam_factor: 5.98176
  },
  {
    timestamp: "2020-09-30T07:03:00.132Z",
    jam_factor: 4.15984
  }
];

function filter(segment) {
  let result = [];
  let count = 0;
  let prevIsTen, j;
  for (let i = 0; i < segment.length; i++) {
    let isTen = segment[i].jam_factor === 10;
    if (isTen === prevIsTen) {
      if (++count == 3 && j) {
        result.push(segment[j]);
        segment[j].start_end = isTen ? 'start' : 'end'
      }
    } else {
      j = count < 3 ? 0 : i;
      count = 1;
    }
    prevIsTen = isTen;
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(filter(segment));
console.log(segment);
```